# Android studio play an audio file without a button click

Tags: android, audio

I recently paid someone to develop an experimental app for me. The app basically shows a picture with a couple of "buttons" in the corner that have other functions. Essentially, I also want an audio file to play automatically when the image is presented without having to click a button (this sort of function is already written into the script). I'm not a programmer (which is why I had to hire someone) but he couldn't figure out how to do this either. I just wondered whether anyone has any suggestions I can try?

Here is the code that controls the audio files:
    public class ObjectFragment extends Fragment {

```
private int index;
private int trackID;
private int videoID;
private boolean visible;

private Integer[] imageIDs = {R.drawable.c1, R.drawable.c2, R.drawable.c3,
        R.drawable.k1, R.drawable.k2, R.drawable.k3,
        R.drawable.m1, R.drawable.m2, R.drawable.m3};

private Integer[] trackIDs = {R.raw.chatten, R.raw.chatten, R.raw.chatten,
        R.raw.kobo, R.raw.kobo, R.raw.kobo,
        R.raw.manu, R.raw.manu, R.raw.manu};

private Integer[] videos = {R.raw.chatten_vid2, R.raw.kobo_vid2, R.raw.manu_vid2};

static ObjectFragment newInstance(int i) {
    ObjectFragment f = new ObjectFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", i);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

/**
 * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
 */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    index = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("index") : 0;
    trackID = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("index") : 0;
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    visible = true;

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
    final Button videoButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video);
    videoButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(motionEvent)==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                MainActivity.getPerson().formatString(System.nanoTime()-MainActivity.initTime, "button", motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY(), "video");
            return false;
        }
    });
    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.word);
    final int word;


    ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageResource(imageIDs[index]);

    //Change values here!!!
    if(index<4) {
        word=3;
        tv.setText("Chatten");
        videoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snapchatten2);
        videoID=0;
    }
    else if(index <8) {
        word=7;
        tv.setText("Kobo");
        videoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snapkobo2);
        videoID=1;
    }
    else {
        word=11;
        tv.setText("Manu");
        videoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snapmanu2);
        videoID=2;
    }

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.abc).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            String text="";
            if(word==3)
                text = "Chatten";
            else if(word==7)
                text = "Kobo";
            else if(word==11)
                text="Manu";
            if(MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(motionEvent)==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                MainActivity.getPerson().formatString(System.nanoTime()-MainActivity.initTime, "button", motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY(), "abc "+text);
            return false;
        }
    });
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.abc).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MainActivity.music.stop();
            MainActivity.music.doInBackground(new Object[]{trackIDs[trackID]});
            MainActivity.music.setLooping(false);
            MainActivity.music.play();
            while (!MainActivity.playBgMusic()) ;
        }
    });

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.babylabs).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(motionEvent) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                MainActivity.getPerson().formatString(System.nanoTime() - MainActivity.initTime, "button", motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY(), "babylabs");
            return false;
        }
    });
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.babylabs).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (tv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return;
            }
            visible = false;
            MainActivity.back_counter = 1;
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    videoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            videoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            MainActivity.music.pause();
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + videos[videoID]));

            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });

            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    videoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    MainActivity.music.play();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet with ViewTreeObserver solution. It tells you when the image is drawn.

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = yourImage.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                yourImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                yourImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }

            // do additional stuff here

            MainActivity.music.play();
        } 
    });
```

You can add this code to your oncreate method. Don't forget to prepare your player before. Maybe you want to add a onloadcomplete listener.